# Странности JS присваивание

Tags: javascript

Почему такая конструкция отработает корректно?

```
var a = NaN = "asdf"
```

или

```
var a = Infinity = "asdf"
```

Comment: Потому что почему бы и нет, NaN и Infinity являются корректными именами для переменных

Comment: @andreymal Ты бы еще сказал, что if является корректным именем

Comment: @Darth Пруф, что они не являются корректными именами

Comment: Кстати, интересный факт: `typeof NaN` и `typeof Infinity` - является `"number"`

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что в нестрогом режиме присваивание readonly-свойств просто игнорируется. А именно такими свойствами и являются `NaN`, `Infinity` и `undefined`. Подробнее про отличия строгого и нестрого режима можно прочитать [в соответствующем вопросе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435547/178988).

```js
var obj = { get x() { return 42 } }

function nonStrict() {
  console.log(obj.x = 10)
  console.log(obj.x)
}

function strict() {
  'use strict'

  console.log(obj.x = 10)
  console.log(obj.x)
}

nonStrict()
strict()
```

```js
function nonStrict() {
  console.log(NaN = 10)
}

function strict() {
  'use strict'
  console.log(NaN = 10)
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "NaN"))

nonStrict()
strict()
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: В не строгом режиме у нас переменная NaN все таки становится на какое то время равной  "asdf" иначе как переменная a стала равна  "asdf" ||

var a = NaN = "asdf"

Comment: @good_web_master, присваивание как бы возвращает правую часть. Само присваивание игнорируется, а значение дальше идёт то, которое ты присваивал.

Comment: @good_web_master, не становится. В `a` присваивается **результат присваивания**, а это значение стоящее справа от `=`

Answer (score 1):

Думаю дело в том, что `NaN` и `Infinity` не являются управляющими конструкциями языка, как `if` и подобные и не являются константами.

Если взглянуть на описание [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) и [Infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity), то там чётко написано, что это **свойство** *глобального объекта* window. А раз это свойство, то имя переменной с таким же именем? объявленное через `var` вполне себе допустимо и никак не конфликтует ни с чем и не выбрасывает ошибок.